# how to access members of a static inner class from main method of different class

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

Stack overflow just wants me to write more here.

```
Class A{
    static Class B{
         int i,j;
   }
    B method(int x){
        // how to return object of type B
    }
}

Class Main(){
   // how do i call method B here
}
```

Comment: "Stack overflow just wants me to write more here." and there is a reason for that. You didn't explain what is stopping you from writing your own code. Did you encounter any problems? In other words you need to describe [what have you tried already](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: There's no such thing as a static inner class.

Answer (score 0):

If **Main** and **A** are in the same package this should already work as follows:

A.java:

```
class A {
    static Class B{
        int i,j;
    }
    B method(int x){
        // how to return object of type B
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // how do i call method B here
       A a = new A();
       A.B b = a.method();
    }
}
```

If they are in separate packages you'll need to declare classes A and B public.